# Using assignment statement in c for loop condition

Tags: c

Is statement A & B are equal?

```
int i;
char a[] = "Hello\n";
char b[100];
```

Statement A,

```
for(i=0; b[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    b[i] = a[i];
```

Statement B,

```
for(i=0; (b[i] = a[i]) != '\0'; ++i)
      ;
```

Comment: `for(i=0; b[i] != '\0'; ++i,(b[i-1] = a[i-1]))` . but i think it should be `a` that is to be checked.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are different:

- The first loop checks the value of `b[i]` *before* the assignment;
- The second loop checks the value of `b[i]` *after* the assignment.

As the result, the second loop will copy the content of `a` into `b`, and stop after copying `\0`. The first loop would stop copying as soon as it encounters the first `\0` in `b` before performing a copy, disregarding any zeros that it may find in `a`.

Comment: i think `a` should be the loop controller in his question?

Comment: @Koushik, I was thinking to write an equivalent code for       while((d[i] = s[i]) != '\0'){
       ++i;
}

Comment: @Clement no problem but `while((d[i] = s[i]) != '\0'){ ++i; }` is different from what you are asking. this while will store the boolean results in `d`.

Comment: @Koushik No, because of parentheses the `while` loop from the comment would do the right thing.

Comment: @Clement The second loop is the same as the `while` from your comment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i totally missed out the parentheses. sorry. but otherwise without it my comment would be correct rite?

Answer (score 2):

**No they are not.**

In statement A, you are checking `b[i]` before assigning value to it

In the second statement, you are assigning value before checking.

The 1st one is like a *while loop*, where is the second one is like a *do - while loop*.

Answer (score 0):

NO they are not the same

in the second you have set the `b[i]` value and then you have checked `!= '\0'`.

in the  fisrt you have checked the `b[i]` `!= '\0'` before set it

I can suggest to you also:

```
int i = -1;
while(b[++i] = a[i]);
```

Comment: wont this become undefined in c?since `=` is not a sequence point?